# Command-line arg to int with atoi in C

Tags: c, string, int, user-input

Hi I have written a program with the following useage:

```
./borlc 2 -compress file1.txt file2.txt
```

The first argument (2), I need to store it in an int, so I tried to do the following:

```
int t;
t = atoi(argv[1]);
```

however I get a segmentation error in this. Is there any better way to do what I'm trying to?

Comment: Segmentation fault, he writes

Comment: Ensure `argc > 1` before calling `atoi(argv[1])`.  Suspect parameters are not passed correctly, `argc == 1` and code is doing `atoi(NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your main function defined correctly and check how many parameters you got.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Parameter is missing");
        return 0;
    }

    int t;
    t = atoi(argv[1]);
}
```